# Random walk type problem with time increments

Tags: probability, statistics, random-walk

Imagine you have $\$50$ and every $2$ minutes you either gain or lose $33$ cents. How would you model the evolution of the hypothetical bankroll for the next hour?

My approach based on what i've read about about random walks:

$\sigma=.33\cdot(\frac{60}{2})^.5$

$\mu=50.$

Plug these into a normal distribution to find the probability of having $x$ amount of money after an hour.

Some sources say if $\frac{1}{2}$ then $\sigma$ would have to be divided by $2$. But others just use the square root.

Comment: You will get better/quicker/more answers if you write a bit more neatly (with proper capitalization, punctuation, etc). Also, you can enclose math in dollar signs to make it render nicely. Click the 'edit' button to see how I reformatted your post.